Is it correct to say "write down the words, leaving one cell between them" or "..., leaving one cell between each of them"?

My daughter has a book with cells like the above picture. She has to write down the word "e" several times like that.
Note: In Vietnam, a workbook has cells like that for students to write in
This is one example from Oxford dictionary
Position the tiles, leaving a narrow gap between the edges.
I guess there are more than 2 tiles and so there are more than 2 edges.
They didn't say Position the tiles, leaving a narrow gap between each edge.
Similarly, I guess we can say "write down the words, leaving one-cell gap between them".
If we don't use the noun "gap", then
Is it correct to say "write down the words, leaving one cell between them" or "write down the words, leaving one cell between each of them / each one"?
I think we can also say "write down the words and make sure they are spaced evenly one cell apart".

If the picture is from your daughter's book and this is about describing the exercise accurately, you should note that she is writing letters, not words.

In my day I would have called them squares. Each large square is divided into 16 smaller ones. "Leave a square space between the letters." But I imagine there must be a dozen ways to say this, but would you really say this? Wouldn't the average response be "Do it like this" and show a small child how it's done.

I don't know how useful this question is for future visitors and how many would need to know what to say in that specific situation.

If that is cursive lower-case "L" it needs to be taller, extending into the third block, and skinnier, if it is wanting to use standard proportions for the cursive letter.

Like the second one in on the top row.

Your screenshot looks like it is taken from a spreadsheet such as Excel or Google Sheets, and 'cell' is certainly the correct terminology to refer to each grid space. Cells in spreadsheets or tables are defined spaces. A 'gap' is not a defined space. When writing by hand you leave a 'gap' between each word which you judge by your eye and all may not be precisely equal.
On whether or not to include the word "each" - this is all about clarity. Saying the gap must be between "each" makes it clearer that you mean there should be a gap after every word. Without that, could the reader think you meant something else? Maybe writing the words down is part of a series of exercises - perhaps someone might think you mean leave a gap after each sentence?
Also, I see from the grid that there is not only a space between each word but between each line. Also, I can't see a space after the final word on each line. Are you actually asking for a grid to be populated? In such a case, you might need to explain in more detail.

In Vietnam, a workbook has cells like that for students to write in
